# html content not showing, tried everything

Tags: html

Basically, the content of an html document isn't showing whatsoever on the browser.
This HTML document I made was linked from another html file.

When I open this HTML file on the browser, it is blank, not showing a thing when there is clearly code in it.
I have saved a couple of times and still has not been showing content with every update.

I tried updating and saving before opening, searched on google what is the problem and the solution.
Still there was nothing relevant to my issue. I was expecting for the browser to finally execute the
HTML code but still there was nothing. So I looked at Stack Overflow and here I am now.

Any solutions?

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Aa
    <title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1><i>Aa<i></h1>
<p>Aa</p>
           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use any HTML validator first?

Comment: `<title>` and `<i>` are not closed

Comment: If you press [edit] and then `[<>]` you can make the snippet like I did. In that snippet editor, you will see the end tags are red on other elements because you did not close the tags earlier

Answer (score 2):

The `<title>` tag is not closed properly, you are missing an `/`:

`<title>Aa</title>`

Comment: Please do not answer typo questions. Comment on the question and when you have enough rep to vote, vote to close